# Static keyword in PHP prints 0 value

Tags: php

```
$x = 5;
$y = 10;
function test($a, $b) {
   static $a, $b;
   return $a + $b;
}
print test($a, $b);
```

**Why this code prints 0 as value?**

Comment: What would you expect to get from it?

Comment: `$a` and `$b` don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static` keyword doesn't modify variables, it creates new ones with new values. See this:

```
$x = 5;
static $x;
var_dump($x);
$x = 6;
var_dump($x);
```

By doing:

```
static $a, $b;
```

You have overridden input values of your function with new variables. Since both are undefined (`static $a, $b` is same as `static $a=null, $b=null`), `null + null` equals to `0` thus the output.